# HP Envy 17 3D 2199 el is incredibly slow

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, laptop, ssd

Back in 2012 I bought this laptop which has the following specs:

- Intel Core i7 - 2630QM @ 2.0 Ghz
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM
- AMD Radeon HD 6800M / Intel HD 3000

I even bought a Sandisk SSD 128GB (with windows 10 home installed on it) that I have installed along with the 1TB HDD (that I use for Data)

The computer used to be so slow even when I had only the factory configuration with HDD and Windows 7

The problem it's that is **incredibly slow**, it takes minutes even to load Edge, It is always hot and with fans spinning at max speed. I am not even able to listen to music on spotify while doing other tasks because the pc will slow down too much.

**Am I the only one having this problem? Is there a way I can fix it? I even tried reinstalling a fresh copy of Windows 10 on my SSD but that did not fix the problem.**

I would really appreciate if you could help me out!

**EDIT**
this is my task manager screen, as you can see nor CPU nor RAM is nearly a half of usage.

[image: task manager]

Comment: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01657439

Comment: From your question, I first wondered how you managed to get Windows 10 back in 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can think of with the combination of slowness, lack of CPU and disk activity, and no swapping, is a combination of the processor being very underclocked or throttled + bad graphics drivers causing you to always use the discrete graphics chip rather than the cooler and less power hungry Intel HD 3000 graphics.

Though actually, it could just be bad graphics drivers so it's only using the hotter AMD graphics chip, and if the cooling in the laptop is poor enough, it may be throttling the CPU and memory down significantly to prevent damage. This seems likely to me since the laptop is already 4 years old, and laptops are often known to have poor quality cooling (either because of design constraints or just poor quality work on the assembly).

First, I'd confirm this by checking to see if it's using the discrete graphics chip. If you can force it to use the Intel graphics chip instead, and things improve, then that would support my suspicions. If you want to be able to use the AMD graphics chip (and can find Windows 10 drivers that work for your laptop), and you're comfortable with servicing laptop hardware, then I would go ahead and check that. Make sure the airflow is good and blow out any dust that's there. Reapply the thermal paste between the heatsinks and CPU and GPU, reassemble, and then see if it runs as hot and slow as before. That should, hopefully fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Hp envy 17 2199el 3D user here.

Writing this just in case someone still needs to fix this problem.

> The problem it's that is incredibly slow, it takes minutes even to load Edge, It is always hot and with fans spinning at max speed. I am not even able to listen to music on spotify while doing other tasks because the pc will slow down too much.

This is caused by HP coolsense 2.0, for some reason when it's enabled it underclocks your processor down to 80 Mhz (Bug?) and spins the fans to the max. I've resolved by just disabling it.

JFYI: For some reason the latest windows 10 video drivers don't work (black screen at boot as of 6/5/2017), to fix this you have to disable the auto-updates after the rollback. If you need updated drivers just install the UNIFL but you won't be able to use 3D capabilities anymore.